# eBay Trading API Notifications to web server appear to send no data PHP

Tags: php, post, ebay-api

I am trying to get the eBay Trading API to send notifications to my web server, but they appear to be sending no data.

eBay is successfully calling my server, I see the logs and the empty data from a var_dump. Here is my code in my endpoint to try to test the content of the data sent by eBay. It is supposed to be sent via POST and contains XML/SOAP data on the status of the item.

Ref: https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/features-guide/default.html#Notifications/Notif-ItemClosed.html%3FTocPath%3DWorking%2520with%2520Platform%2520Notifications%7C_____25

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

$logfileName = 'feedbackFromEbayApi' . date('Ymd') . '.log';

$dataWrite = var_dump_ret($_POST);

file_put_contents($logfileName, "DATA:" . $dataWrite, FILE_APPEND);

function var_dump_ret($mixed = null) {
  ob_start();
  var_dump($mixed);
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $content;
}
```

So to test it I add an item to eBay, then I close it to trigger the 'ItemClosed' event. This provokes eBay into sending the data to my endpoint, where it meets this code above.

But all I get when I look in the log file is this:

```
 DATA:array(0) {
 }
```

Also changing the line to:

```
$dataWrite = json_encode($_POST);
```

Also shows no POST data...

```
DATA:[]
```

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

$logfileName = 'feedbackFromEbayApi' . date('Ymd') . '.log';

$dataWrite = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );

file_put_contents($logfileName, "DATA:" . $dataWrite);

function var_dump_ret($mixed = null) {
  ob_start();
  var_dump($mixed);
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $content;
}
```